# Bank solvency statement for UK visa

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork, applications, proof-provenance-of-funds

I applied for UK tourist visa (6 months) 2 weeks ago. I will go to London for only a weekend (3 days). I live in the Netherlands. I have a question regarding financial evidence. My bank isn't able to provide bank account transactions in English, and I didn't want to get them translated since it was too expensive. Instead, they could provide a solvency statement in English, in which my current balance at that time, account number, home address and time since when I am a customer for that bank are written. That statement also includes a clause that I use the account properly.

I have also provided my salaryslips from my company. But since I didn't provide them a transaction records, despite most people recommend, I still doubt that whether they would accept the solvency statement. Considering that there is still a week for them to process the application, I am a bit edgy at the moment :)

I am wondering if it is OK to provide such a document as a financial evidence, where only my current balance, account number and address is visible but not the transaction details.

Comment: Weird that a Dutch bank wouldn't be able to do a statement in English. Fairly standard even in less English friendly countries. Would a Dutch one not be OK? Its the numbers they're interested in, the titles on the tables shouldn't be an issue

Comment: Indeed it is really strange. My bank is ING. I called their customer service, went to their one of the branches, all they could provide me was this letter. The visa document list was very specific and clear that the documents have to be in English only, so I hesitated including the bank statements.

Answer (score 2):

No, it’s unlikely a solvency statement will suffice. UKVI are interested in more than just your bank balance, as explained here [Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab)